# August 2012 Moderator Election Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

***The Town Hall Chat took place on Thursday, August 23rd, at 12:00:00Z UTC / This is at 8am EDT*** - digest is available [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/august-2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest).

Normally we try to schedule these at the start of the phase, but there was a bit of a mixup on the information of the election's timing. Namely that it already started last week, not this week. Whoops.

As such, the Town Hall Chat is a little delayed, but we'll still be holding one. Some have already voted, **keep in mind that you can change your election vote at any time**, so there's no harm in coming to the Town Hall Chat to either get reassurance for your choice, or to shift your decision.

Candidates have already been contacted and scheduling has been done, as you probably noticed before you reached this point in the message.

Here are the details so far:

- Because of the delay in scheduling, we're shooting to schedule the event in the span of Wednesday - Friday (22th-24th). There is no second stage editing because this phase has already been done.
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=security.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.